# Relacionamento Eloquent do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho 3 tabelas:

```
-- tipos
id
nome

-- usuarios
id
tipo_id
nome
email

-- atividades
id
usuario_id
descricao
```

Estou usando o Eloquent para capturar as atividades e os dados do usuário da ativade:

```
$results = Atividades::with('Usuario')->get();
```

Porém preciso pegar também o tipo do usuário, já tentei:

```
$results = Atividades::with('Usuario')->with('Tipo')->get();
```

Mas não retorna os dados do tipo do usuário, somente os dados do usuário, alguém saberia como faria esta consulta?

Comment: `with('Usuario', 'Tipo')->get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar mais de um parametro no metodo `with`, faça da seguinte maneira:

```
$results = Atividades::with('Usuario', 'Tipo')->get();
```

Para confirmar você pode consultar [a documentação do laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)